# Debian NFS client-side permissions issue

Tags: debian, permissions, nfs

I have the following environment:

host1:
Debian 12 with zfs 2.1.11 : open ldap server with default packages, nfs-utils 2.6

host2:
Debian 12: open ldap client with default packages, nfs-utils 2.6

On the ldap server side, I have two groups created, primarygroup1 and primarygroup2, and the user user1 belongs to the group primarygroup2

Server side

```
getent group:
primarygroup1:*:1000001:
primarygroup2:*:1000002:

getent passwd:
user1:x:1000001:1000002:user1:/home/user1:/bin/false
```

The server provides a dataset via NFS with a file with permissions

NFS expots:

```
exportfs -v
/tank/d1 <world>(sync,wdelay,hide,fsid=9a31889cb81531154198e4c3c5156b74,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

File permissions:

```
getfacl /tank/d1/file.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tank/d1/file.txt
# owner: root
# group: primarygroup1
user::rwx
group::r--
other::---
```

Client side:

NFS mount

```
mount
192.168.164.200:/tank/d1 on /mnt/testnfs type nfs
(rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.164.200,mountvers=3,mountport =53721,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.164.200)
```

Permissions on the file

```
getfacl /mnt/testnfs/file.txt
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/testnfs/file.txt
# owner: root
# group: primarygroup1
user::rwx
group::r--
other::---

getent group:
primarygroup1:*:1000001:
primarygroup2:*:1000002:

getent passwd:
user1:x:1000001:1000002:user1:/home/user1:/bin/false
```

The problem is that on the client side user1 does not have permission to read the file, it does not belong to primarygroup1 and yet it can read the file.

```
user1@deb12nfsclient:/root$ cat /mnt/testnfs/file.txt
####### data ######
```

Restarting the NFS server and remounting  sometimes helps, but in most cases not work.
Additionally, I noticed that after about 15 minutes, these permissions work correctly on their own without restarting the NFS server

After approximately 15 minutes:

```
user1@deb12nfsclient:/root$ cat /mnt/testnfs/file.txt
cat: /mnt/testnfs/file.txt: Permission denied
```

On the client side, I used the mounting options: noac, actimeo=0 but it didn't help.

Does anyone know why it behaves this way? Is there any way to shorten this time so that the permissions work properly?

Regards
Adam